# How can I disable Alt+Space native hotkey in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Windows 10 has `Alt+Space` as a default hotkey for opening the menu bar of a windows with the choices of Minimizing/Maximizing it.

I'm using Kdenlive and Kdenlive wants to use `Alt+Space` as a hotkey for playing a video in a loop. Unfortuntely, when I press the hotkey Windows 10 processes the hotkey without the information getting passed to the app.

Given that I don't need the native hotkey, is there a way I can remove it?

Comment: Why not change the `kdenlive` hot-key under `Settings` -> `Configure Shortcuts...`? This seems a better idea than changing a basic system setting for the sake of a single application. You seem to be asking an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @AFH I don't like the general system setting in the first place.

Comment: It's not a case of the XY problem. OP is asking to globally disable the hotkey since the functionality is generally not useful to him.

Comment: Instead of disabling the key it might be better to change it to Win-space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remembered that Autohotkey can map keys to F13 till F24 and used:

```
!Space::
Send {F13}
return
```

To get Autohotkey to press F13 and then set F13 to be the key that's used by Kdenlive for this purpose via `Settings -> Configure Shortcuts`.

Comment: this is a not a valid solution as it doesn't answer the original issue.

Comment: Worked like a charm and opens the possibility for so much additional configurationб using f13+ keys as a kind of a buffer when you need to assign something to built in shortcut which the windows OS itself does not allow you tor remap. Man, you are genius!

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> hotkey is taken by Windows system by default.

However with the help of a 3rd party solution you can override this setting and take control over Windows by not letting them to steal the hotkey combination.

1. Download [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com) and install it.
2. Create a new file in Notepad or your default editor and insert these 2 lines:

   ```
   ; it allows to make a rule which is applied only when windows contains the given title
   SetTitleMatchMode, 2 

   ; obviously below you write the title that is contained in your program's window 
   #IfWinActive, Kdenlive
   !Space::Return ; ! stands for Alt key
   ```
3. Save it somewhere easy to access it as *Whatever*.**ahk** (and not as .txt)
4. Double click on it (or Run as Administrator) and it will trigger AutoHotKey to execute it and have it loaded. Now the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> hotkey does not call the Windows default actionwhen is hit in a window with the given title (Kdenlive).

I suggest to put it on your startup programs for not having to execute it manually each time you reboot your system.

You can find more information on how to program hotkeys in AutoHotKey by scripting on https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

Comment: This prevents windows from engaging in it's behavior but it doesn't let kdenlive process the hotkey event.

Comment: After disabling it, try to hit the following key sequence in your application -> `Space + Alt + Space`. However did you indeed checked if `Alt+Space` is still working in your application after applying AutoHotKey solution?

Comment: Yes, I did check and hitting the key sequence also does nothing.

Comment: As I mentioned at the end of my answer, there is a link where you can find more information on how to script your key based on your preferences and rules. Anyway I edited my answer with new script code. Make sure you reload the your AHK file by right click or close it and open it again.

Comment: I do use Autohotkey quite regularly and the code you proposed doesn't do what I want here. Your code simply lets Autohotkey eat the keypress so that no other program responds to the keypress neither Windows nor Kdenlive.

Comment: You probably did not use it because in my Windows 10 is tested right now and `Alt+Space` changes behavior only to Kdenlive (which happens to run as well) and it remains as Windows default function to all the other ones. Do you want me to upload a YouTube video in case you need it visualized ? There is no trouble for me if it helps you.

Comment: It's certainly possible that your computer does something that allows Kdenlive to capture the key but mine currently doesn't with that code.

Comment: @Christian I checked his code and it works for me as well with my custom photoshop hotkeys. There is definitely some mistake by your side.

Comment: Does NOT work on Win 11

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> has been defined to open the current application's system menu since before dinosaurs.  There is a feature in PowerToys which replaces this with a search feature.  If you don't like this, disable it in PowerToys.

Answer (score 1):

download powertoys
https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys and disable this shortcut.

1. install
2. open program and go to keyboard manager
3. find shortcut section
4. remap a shortcut, type the shortcut in the first box that says physical shortcut (in this case alt space) and select disable as the new mapping in the second box
5. apply by hitting ok

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for fix for this problem I recommend downloading https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys and disabling this shortcut.

1. Install and Run PowerToys Setup
2. Select "PowerToys Run" from the left menu
3. Toggle this setting to "Off", or, reassign the shortcut to something else

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Explaining HOW to use PowerToys to fix this problem will make this an answer. Right now it is only a comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1135526)